# 301 redirection not working for existing file in folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the folder whitepapers. I have the file `test1.pdf` in whitepapers folder.
I want to redirect to `test.domain.com` while accessing the file as

```
test.domain.com/whitepapers/test1.pdf
```

I have placed my `.htaccess` in the folder Whitepapers

```
 Redirect 301 ^/WhitePapers/test1.pdf   https://test.domain.com
```

but `redirection` not happen

Comment: Can you check if your `mod_rewrite` is enabled and `AllowOverride All
    Require all granted` is written for that directory?

Comment: The `Redirect` directive does not use regular expression syntax, so the `^` is definitively wrong.

Comment: Also, is it `/WhitePapers` or `/whitepapers`??

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?